# Show recently modified or uploaded documents

Tags: 2010, web-part, document-library, list-view

I'd like to display a list of the most recently modified documents across all document libraries in a site in Sharepoint 2010.
It seems that the Content Query webpart might do this for me, but the filter options seem to require me to specify an actual date (or relative date). Unfortunately some sites are more active than others, so for some sites recent might mean "this year" and for others it might mean "this week".

Answer (score 2):

Create a view... Sort it by the Modified Date... Specify the item limit... You can even use filter for further more requirement...

Comment: Is "create a view" in Sharepoint designer?

Comment: Yes.. you can create a view from SharePoint designer...

Comment: I can see how to do this for a single document library, but is it possible to do this across all the document libraries on a site?

Comment: If you want to have it for all libraries.. then.. you should be writing code... which creates a view dynamically on all the libraries...

Answer (score 1):

Create new view, and modify the following settings
sort : 1st column by modified, 2nd column by Modified by
Folders: Show all items without folders
Item Limit : reduce it to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I've used this back in the SP 2003/2007 days:  http://smarttools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=What%27s%20New&referringTitle=Home

I ended up writing my own SP2010 version which is very similar but uses the changelog to get the latest items for lists that are over the listviewthreshhold.

Comment: I've currently got something working with the content query webpart, but the display isn't in a list (document library style) as the users expect. Additionally I have to configure the search query element for each site.